# Spark driver and executor in same machine

Tags: apache-spark

In an EMR cluster or any cluster is it possible that YARN allocate driver and executor in same EC2 instance?
I want to know if driver can utilize the storage and processing power of 1 EC2 instance or some part of this instance will be used for serving other spark jobs running in the cluster. This could cause my driver to run out of memory.

I think Resource manager decide this based on the cluster resource availability?

Answer (score 0):

In non-AWS EMR: driver and executorS can be on same machine / instance.

In AWS EMR: driver may run on Master Node or one of Core Instances --> so on same EC2 instance.

Incidentally, on EMR YARN like aspects run on Master Node.

Comment: When deploy mode cluster is used wouldn't master be running on one of the core/task nodes. Here we dont have a guarantee that driver run only on core node. Is that right?

Comment: Can and may. Not necessarily.